# Cloud optimized GeoTIFF creation for DEM GeoTIFF

Tags: cloud-optimized-geotiff

[image: values of pixels differ in source Geotiff and its COG derivates]

I came across the problem that when converting DEM GeoTIFF into COG then final COG slightly differs from that of GeoTIFF. Basic stats data are usually in compliance with each other but when having closer look at the particular pixels I see they differ. Mostly, difference is not that dramatic but some pixels show already significant distinctions. This happens regardless of the applied creation option in GDAL, e.g.:

```
gdal_translate -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -of COG -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co MAX_Z_ERROR=0 …
```

```
gdal_translate -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -of COG -co COMPRESS=NONE….
```

I guess it has to do something with defualt resampling in GDAL.

Is there appropriate resampling option for not altering the original data?

So far I did not apply particular resampling methods in GDAL command line.

Comment: When deciding the single question you wish to ask in this particular question I would avoid asking for a script.

Comment: Can you provide a tiny sample file?

Comment: I am not sure if i can provide source and converted raster files but i can provide the gdal command i used and resulted raster show differences in particular pixels as shown in an attached picture (Chrast -original tiff, Chrast_cog* - converted cog files)

gdal commands:
gdal_translate -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -of COG -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co MAX_Z_ERROR=0 Chrast.tiff Chrast_cog2.tiff

gdal_translate -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -of COG -co COMPRESS=none Chrast.tiff Chrast_cog3.tiff

Comment: Try also with `-co OVERVIEWS=NONE` https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/cog.html. COG without overviews is not so cloud friendly but at least the test should reveal if the difference that you see comes from hitting the resampled overviews instead of the full resolution pixels.

Comment: Applying this options /--co OVERVIEWS=NONE/ seems to work perfectly - no altering data any more - values of original file are exactly the same as converted cog. So the noticed difference in values come from hitting the resampled overviews instead of full res raster. Thanks a lot.